# Id tag and file signature?

Tags: file

I open a binary file in notepad and see the first few bytes of it are encoded as JHW, I have no idea what tools I can use to "comprehend" the content of a binary file. Could you offer me a hint to read it properly?

Please, just a hint is enough.

Comment: Why use notepad for binary files? Use a hex editor.

Answer (score 2):

Well, many files use a "magic number" to identify themselves. A magic number is like a signature that some files use usually at the beginning of the file, and it can be formed by many bytes. This "magic number" usually is unique.

For a more detailed information please read this Wikipedia article:  [Magic number (programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)

... and good luck.